# Create groups of items from separate tables

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have multiple models (events, chores, bills, and lists), which each have their own table. I want to be able to group any of these instances together, for example group an event with a list of items to buy for it, and a bill for the cost.

I was thinking each table could have a group id, and I could get other items in a group by merging records from each table where the group_id equals the items group_id.

```
group = Events.find_by_group_id(self.group_id).concat(Bills.find_by_group_id(self.group_id)) ...
```

But that seems like a bad way to do it.

Another way I thought to do it was to use a polymorphic relation between two of the items

```
tag
item_1_id | item_1_type | item_2_id | item_2_type
----------+-------------+-----------+------------
```

But in the example above (a group of three different items) would require six records, two between each pair, for each item to know of all other items in the group.

Is there a way to do this with joins, should I redesign some of the tables?